# Laravel 4 Error: Undefined method shutdown

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Help I am new to laravel and I dont know how to fix this Error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::shutdown()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The problem is most likely you are using laravel the app from the github develop branch and using composer to install the rest of the system. The problem is the files from composer are over a month old (4.0.0-beta3) and the git stuff is bleeding edge.

One solution to this problem is to change the composer.json file in your application root from

```
    "require": {
            "laravel/framework": "4.0.*"
    },
```

to

```
    "require": {
            "laravel/framework": "4.0.*@dev"
    },
```

Run composer update and the system will pull down the latest and greatest (and possibly broken) files from Laravel 4.

Comment: The solution worked for me, and explanation makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the last line in the index.php file in your public directory for a quick fix.

// $app->shutdown();

Answer (score 0):

You should not uncomment anything, instead make sure you have all yhe dependencies setup correctly. The shutdown method is there for a reason, and uncommenting the method could/will have consequences.

Instead you can follow these steps:

1.- Make sure you have PHP >= 5.3.7 (if your on OSX i suggest using brewed PHP)

Install guide:

https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php

2.- Make sure you have MCrypt installed. If not, you can install it with homebrew

```
    brew search mcrypt
    brew install php53-mcrypt *OR* php54-mcrypt
```

3.- Install the dev branch of laravel & composer install it

```
    git clone -o framework -b develop https://github.com/laravel/laravel YourApp
    git checkout --orphan master
    git commit -m "First commit"
```

4.- Updating your app

```
    git fetch framework
    git merge --squash -m "Upgrading the framework" framework/develop
```